# Problema con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

El problema es el siguiente:

Quiero generar una url del tipo https://www.midomio.com/nombre-variable

He puesto lo siguiente en el htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*midominio.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.midominio.com/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L,R]
```

y en el fichero php que hace la llamada he puesto lo siguiente:

```
$url_dinamica = "post/".$url_que_genero_dinamicamente;
```

Tal como está ahora, me hace perfectamente la llamada al fichero post.php, comentar que este es un fichero único en el que cambio los valores por variables que cojo de la BD.

El problema es que actualmente me muestra la URL de esta forma:

https://www.midominio.com/post/url_que_genero_dinamicamente

y lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

https://www.midominio.com/url_que_genero_dinamicamente

es decir, quiero que me quite lo de post.

El fichero generado no existe, lo genera dinámicamente el fichero post.php, cambiando el contenido de las variables que recoge de la BD.

Comment: y si quitas el `"post/".` al generar la url?

Comment: Si hago eso, si sale la url de la forma que quiero, pero entonces no me funciona, se va a una página en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

- si el filename de lo que pido no es un archivo (ejemplo: /post.php)
- si el filename de lo que pido no es una carpeta (ejemplo /css)
- entonces tomar todo lo que viene como filename y pasarlo a post.php como id

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

y generas la url así:

```
$url_dinamica = "/".$url_que_genero_dinamicamente;
```

Si da pantalla en blanco puede que haya redireccionamientos debido a otras reglas en el `.htaccess` o falle silenciosamente el `post.php`, en ese caso hay que ir haciendo pruebas sacando reglas del `.htaccess`, tirando `var_dump`/`print_r`, etc... para ver donde está el error.

Un ejemplo completo de redireccionamiento para "pretty urls", simulando una DB en un array:

`index.php`

```
<?php require_once('falsaDB.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Post Example Index</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($tablaPOSTS as $key => $value) : ?>
      <li><a href="./<?php echo $value['slug'];?>" ><?php echo $key.". ".$value['titulo'];?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</body>
```

`falsaDB.php`

```
<?php
$tablaPOSTS = array(
  array('ID'=>0, 'titulo'=>'Un enlace bonito', 'texto'=>'El texto de un enlace bonito'),
  array('ID'=>1, 'titulo'=>'Un post cualquiera', 'texto'=>'El texto de un post cualquiera'),
  array('ID'=>3, 'titulo'=>'Otra prueba de re escritura', 'texto'=>'El texto de otra prueba de re rescritura'),
);

// genero los slugs a partir del título, 
// esto debería hacerse al insertar el registro
foreach($tablaPOSTS as $key=>$post):
  $tablaPOSTS[$key]['slug'] = strToLower(str_replace(' ', '-', $post['titulo']));
endforeach;

// Simulo un select post from tabla where slug=$slug
function findPOSTbySlug($slug, $tabla){
  $key = array_search($slug, array_column($tabla, 'slug'));
  return ($key)?$tabla[$key]:"'$slug' NO ENCONTRADO";
}
?>
```

---

`post.php`

```
<?php require_once('falsaDB.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Post Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
      $elSlug = $_REQUEST['id'];
      $resultado = findPOSTbySlug($elSlug, $tablaPOSTS);
      if (is_array($resultado)) :
  ?>
  <h1><?php echo $resultado['titulo'];?></h1>
  <p><?php echo $resultado['texto'];?></p>
  <?php else : ?>
  <p><?php echo $resultado;?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <pre>
    <?php print_r($resultado); ?>
  </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

---

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

---

- Cambié el patrón de matching para que le pase el "filename" a `post.php` como `id`
- En caso de que quieras pasar parámetros adicionales por ejemplo `/otra-prueba-de-re-escritura?pagina=2` el `pagina=2` lo sacás de `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` que sería la url original sin transformar.
- si es hosting compartido o hay varios virtualhost tal vez tengas que agregar `RewriteBase /` justo antes del primer `RewriteCond`, a veces también influye tener una regla con `[R]` justo antes o un nivel mas arriba.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he probado, pero no me funciona, cuando pulso el link, hace bien la ruta, pero no me genera la página. es decir, va a una página en blanco.

Comment: post.php está en el raiz del dominio?

Comment: Si, la url de post es la siguiente http://www.midomino.com/post.php

Comment: ahí te añadí un ejemplo completo que toma el `/nombre-de-archivo-o-carpeta` y lo pasa al `post.php`

Comment: ok, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, lo prueba y te digo si me funciona.